# reactjs - input not appended even data exists

Tags: reactjs

I am a newbie in ReactJS.

For now, I am trying to set a value name into a state. Even though debugging  through inspect element and the value does exist, but the value still wont appended when viewing from console.log on submit. The CategoryValueName state when console.log on submit in specific shows the value is there, but still won't get appended. Any idea what I miss over here?

Appreciate everyone's help on this.

```
const FormPaymentInstruction = () = > {
    const[CategoryValue, setCategoryValue] = useState("");
    const[CategoryValueName, setCategoryValueName] = useState("");
    const selectCategory = (CategoryValue) = > {
        setCategoryValue(CategoryValue);
    }
    const getCategoryName = (CategoryValue) = > {
        setCategoryValueName(CategoryValue[CategoryValue.value].text);
    }
    const onSubmit = data = > {
        console.log(data);
        if (CategoryValue) {
            formData.append('CategoryValue', CategoryValue);
        } else {
            formData.append('CategoryValue', '');
        }
        if (CategoryValueName) {
            formData.append('CategoryValueName', CategoryValueName);
            console.log(CategoryValueName);
        } else {
            formData.append('CategoryValueName', '');
        }
    }

return (
    <div className="py-2">
        <input type="hidden" name="CategoryValueName" id="CategoryValueName" {...register('CategoryValueName')} value={CategoryValueName} />
        <label>Select Memo for Payment Instruction: <span style={{ color:'red' }}>*</span></label>
        <select 
            name="CategoryValue"
            id="CategoryValue"
            className="block w-full br-5 border-gray-300 rounded-md" 
            {...register('CategoryValue')}
            onChange={(e) => { selectCategory(e.target.value);getCategoryName(e.target) }}
            value={CategoryValue}
        >
            <option value="" disabled>-- Please select one --</option>
            <option value="1">Sponsorship</option>
            <option value="2">Donation</option>
        </select>
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging out, I figured that I missed one step which is to set the value, that's why the value is not set.

```
const getCategoryName = (CategoryValueName) => {
        setCategoryValueName(CategoryValueName[CategoryValueName.value].text);
        setValue('CategoryValueName', CategoryValueName[CategoryValueName.value].text);
}
```